# @use in sass causes errors

Tags: css, sass

I am having troubles with SASS @use. How does css file contain the @use from SASS? And it keeps saying $font-size is not defined.
[image]

Note: It still works if I use "@import" and SASS version when I ran "npm sass -v" is 8.20. Thank you! Sorry for using picture, I cannot get the code format right.

Comment: `dart-sass` is the only compiler that can use `@use`. You are using lib sass or ruby sass. https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use - see the very first line about compatibility

Comment: @disinfor I ran "npm i sass". Was it not dart-sass?

Comment: No, it's probably Node Sass, which is a wrapper for LibSass. https://github.com/sass/dart-sass/blob/main/README.md#javascript-api

Comment: @disinfor according to this https://www.npmjs.com/package/dart-sass, dart-sass is deprecated and its name was change to sass

Comment: `dart-sass` has not been deprecated. https://github.com/sass/dart-sass - as you can see, it's still being actively developed and maintained. The package name may have changed. That aside, you still most likely do not have dart-sass installed.

Comment: @disinfor Thank you! I figured it out the issue. First, it had nothing to do with node-sass or dart-sass. Second, I was watching sass using a vscode extension called "Live Sass Compiler" but when I switched to "sass --watch scss", it worked but Sass has to be installed globally.

Comment: Ahh...that will do it! Glad you got it figured out.